# How do you provide conditional checkout options depending on whats in the cart?

Tags: 7, commerce

Is it possible to provide different payment options depending on what is in the cart? Say someone wanted to purchase a service vs a physical product. For service related items, I want to be able to provide a payment option of Bitcoins and if its physical products, provide paypal. if they have a service and product in their cart it would only provide paypal as an option. Can this be done via rules and which rules would i need to edit?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already set different product types to handle different kind of product.

So what you have to do is, by default disable payment methods and set them one by one in rules to make a payment option available if certain product type in in cart.

- Add Event "Select available payment methods for an order"
- Add Condition "Order contains products of particular product type"
- Add Action "Enable payment method: `(Your Payment Method)`"

I have done something like this for COD(Cash on Delivery) for certain product type in certain postal codes.

Comment: would you have a snapshot by any chance? thanks!

Comment: @duckx Snapshot for what ? You should better try & inform where it doesn't work if you get any issue with the answer given by me. And please don't ask those question where you can't even acknowledge the person who is giving answer, whether it's working for you or not like - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79381/in-drupal-7-commerce-1-x-is-there-a-way-to-include-the-price-into-the-dropdown/79385#79385